# ImportError Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

I'm having an endless amount of problems with the most recent PyCharm (PyCharm 2016.2.3) with Python 3.5.2. Half of the time the packages aren't available to download but let's stick to the problem at hand. I am trying to run the following code in Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

only to receive an ImportError message 'ImportError: cannot import name "keys"'.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try execute this code in windows console?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling selenium using PIP and configure the same in pycharm.

Follow below steps to re-install/upgrade selenium using PIP.

set path: \Python35\Scripts in environment variables.

Open cmd. type pip install --upgrade selenium.

In pycharm make sure you have correct python interpreter is selected.
You can check that from Run-> Edit configuration: select the correct python interpreter.